# Linker errors from updating AudioKit 4.9 and AKAppleSequencer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audiokit

I am going through the process of updating my app to the latest AudioKit 4.9, and am running into some issues.

After updating my Pod, I discovered that I needed to replace the `AKSequencer`s throughout my app with the new(old) `AKAppleSequencer`, and have made those updates.

However, I am now getting a number of Undefined Symbol errors that are thrown from `AKAppleSequencer` and `AKMIDIListener`, preventing me from being able to build.

I've made sure to update all my pods, do a pod install for all of them, and clean my build folder.

Not really sure how to proceed with an error like this, was wondering if this is an obvious issue with something about my project / Pods / implementation, or if there is an issue with the update I am unaware of?

Thanks!

---

```
Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for AudioKit.AKAppleSequencer
Undefined symbol: (extension in AudioKit):AudioKit.AKMIDIListener.receivedMIDISystemCommand(_: [Swift.UInt8], portID: Swift.Int32?, offset: Swift.UInt64) -> ()
Undefined symbol: (extension in AudioKit):AudioKit.AKMIDIListener.receivedMIDIAftertouch(noteNumber: Swift.UInt8, pressure: Swift.UInt8, channel: Swift.UInt8, portID: Swift.Int32?, offset: Swift.UInt64) -> ()
Undefined symbol: (extension in AudioKit):AudioKit.AKMIDIListener.receivedMIDIPitchWheel(_: Swift.UInt16, channel: Swift.UInt8, portID: Swift.Int32?, offset: Swift.UInt64) -> ()
Undefined symbol: (extension in AudioKit):AudioKit.AKMIDIListener.receivedMIDIAftertouch(_: Swift.UInt8, channel: Swift.UInt8, portID: Swift.Int32?, offset: Swift.UInt64) -> ()
Undefined symbol: (extension in AudioKit):AudioKit.AKMIDIListener.receivedMIDIController(_: Swift.UInt8, value: Swift.UInt8, channel: Swift.UInt8, portID: Swift.Int32?, offset: Swift.UInt64) -> ()
Undefined symbol: AudioKit.AKAppleSequencer.__allocating_init() -> AudioKit.AKAppleSequencer
Undefined symbol: (extension in AudioKit):AudioKit.AKMIDIListener.receivedMIDINoteOff(noteNumber: Swift.UInt8, velocity: Swift.UInt8, channel: Swift.UInt8, portID: Swift.Int32?, offset: Swift.UInt64) -> ()
Undefined symbol: (extension in AudioKit):AudioKit.AKMIDIListener.receivedMIDIProgramChange(_: Swift.UInt8, channel: Swift.UInt8, portID: Swift.Int32?, offset: Swift.UInt64) -> ()
Undefined symbol: (extension in AudioKit):AudioKit.AKMIDIListener.receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: Swift.UInt8, velocity: Swift.UInt8, channel: Swift.UInt8, portID: Swift.Int32?, offset: Swift.UInt64) -> ()
```

Comment: Hi there, I think the reason you're not getting more help and even some down ratings is because you have only given the error.  But, that seems a bit harsh so I upvoted. In any event, all I can really offer you is to do a screen share with you to see if I can fix it on your computer.

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/1241